# Angular2 Input() variable prints undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-components, angular-module

I have two components, Full-Layout(Parent Component) and Department (Child Component).

When a variable in Full-Layout is bind and passed to child component, it always claims that it's undefined. I'm not sure why.

**`full-layout.component.html`**

```js
<ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of dropDownItems">
        <a #clicked class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="[item.routerLink]">
           <i class="icon-puzzle"></i>{{item.name}}
           <app-departments [title]="childTitle"></app-departments>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**`full-layout.component.ts`**

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './full-layout.component.html',
})
export class FullLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  public childTitle: string = 'This text is passed to child';
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  dropDownItems = [{
      routerLink: '/departments',
      name: 'Artshums'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/social-buttons',
      name: 'Dentistry'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/cards',
      name: 'Law'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/forms',
      name: 'IOPPN'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/modals',
      name: 'LSM'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/departments',
      name: 'NMS'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/tables',
      name: 'Nursing'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/tabs',
      name: 'SSPP'
    },
    {
      routerLink: '/components/tabs',
      name: 'Health'
    }
  ];
}
```

**`departments.component.ts`**

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-departments',
  templateUrl: './departments.component.html',
  inputs: ['title']
})
export class DepartmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  title:string;

  constructor () {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.title);
  }
}
```

**`departments.module.ts`**

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DepartmentsRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [ DepartmentsComponent ]
})
export class DepartmentsModule {}
```

**`app.module.ts`**

```js
// imports {...}...
// assume necessary imports above

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DepartmentsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FullLayoutComponent,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get `undefined` message when i Print the title in my child component.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks Champs!

Comment: Try getting rid of the "inputs" attribute in the decorator and calling the console log in ngOnChanges

Comment: Sorry, Im new to Angular2, could you please abbreviate? @chrispy

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Input()` above childTitle in your class as

```
export class FullLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    public childTitle: string = 'This text is passed to child';
```

You need to have the same name on your html than your child component attribute and the same attribute in your html than your parent component attribute. Try this:

```
<app-departments [childTitle]="title"></app-departments>
```

Comment: `Input()` wont work, i added `@Input()` and still wont work

Comment: Any thoughts regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these

`@Input() title:string = "";`

or

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.title=""

    }
```

or

```
constructor(){
  this.title="";
}
```

Comment: Regardless of using any of the above, it wont print what it was initiliased in the parent component

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Comment: Hi there. Yes, could I have your details

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please Remove this **inputs** property and try

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-departments',
  templateUrl: './departments.component.html',
  **inputs: ['title']** 
})
```

Comment: Hi, it didnt fix the issue

Comment: Hi, I title is default property of HTML elements. So try to give different name and try :-)

Comment: Ok, Ive changed it to `checking`, it still prints `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [title] as app-department attribut should listen ngFor count :

```
<ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of dropDownItems">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="item.routerLink">
        <i class="icon-puzzle"></i>{{item.name}}
        <app-departments [title]="item"></app-departments>
    </a>
</li>
```

And add to your child component :

```
<p>
  {{title.name}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise the input property in parent component, In your case you are using *ngFor and **DepartmentsComponent** expect some initial value of input property, you can handle @Input property value in **DepartmentsComponent**  template like below and *ng-container* will not introduce any extra element in dom.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="title">
      <!-- paste  departments.component.html code here -->
</ng-container>
```

Another way is you can use **ChangeDetectionStrategy** **OnPush** 
[ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-departments',
  templateUrl: './departments.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DepartmentsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  title:string;

  constructor () {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.title);
  }
}
```